# How can I put the link in telegram group to bot with command

Tags: javascript, telegram, telegraf

My goal is to make a message in telegram group and put the link to bot with command 'subscribe'
How can I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to open the chat with the bot with a link then you can use deeplinking. You can use this URL to redirect anyone to your bot.

```
https://t.me/usernameBot?start
```

You can check more details [here](https://core.telegram.org/bots#deep-linking)